# Packed PE file and weird Header

Tags: windows, malware, pe, unpacking

I'm new to reverse engineering, so I don't know if my question will be easy or not.
Right now I have an exe file, but it seems packed. In the hex Dump I do have the followings :

```
000003d0: 0055 5058 3000 0000 0000 e028 0000 1000  .UPX0......(....
000003e0: 0000 0000 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000003f0: 0000 0000 0080 0000 e055 5058 3100 0000  .........UPX1...
00000400: 0000 4014 0000 f028 0000 3814 0000 0200  ..@....(..8.....
00000410: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0040 0000  .............@..
00000420: e02e 7273 7263 0000 0000 a007 0000 303d  ..rsrc........0=
00000430: 0000 9207 0000 3a14 0000 0000 0000 0000  ......:.........
00000440: 0000 0000 0040 0000 c033 2e39 3300 5550  .....@...3.93.UP
00000450: 5821 0d09 0201 4482 f819 2707 6e6b 290d  X!....D...'.nk).
```

I guess that my file is packed using UPX.
But I'm stuck with the rest of the file because I do have an altered header it seems :

```
00000000: 4d5a 9000 0300 0000 0400 0000 ffff 0000  MZ..............
00000010: b800 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000  ........@.......
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 8000 0000  ................
00000040: 0e1f ba0e 00b4 09cd 21b8 014c cd21 5468  ........!..L.!Th
00000050: 6973 2070 726f 6772 616d 2063 616e 6e6f  is program canno
00000060: 7420 6265 2072 756e 2069 6e20 444f 5320  t be run in DOS
00000070: 6d6f 6465 2e0d 0d0a 2400 0000 0000 0000  mode....$.......
00000080: 5045 0000 4c01 0300 a505 f358 0000 0000  PE..L......X....
[...]
00000250: 4e71 e81b 0068 e81b 004d 5a90 0003 0000  Nq...h...MZ.....
00000260: 0004 0000 00ff ff00 00b8 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000270: 0040 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  .@..............
00000280: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000290: 0000 0000 0080 0000 000e 1fba 0e00 b409  ................
000002a0: cd21 b801 4ccd 2154 6869 7320 7072 6f67  .!..L.!This prog
000002b0: 7261 6d20 6361 6e6e 6f74 2062 6520 7275  ram cannot be ru
000002c0: 6e20 696e 2044 4f53 206d 6f64 652e 0d0d  n in DOS mode...
000002d0: 0a24 0000 0000 0000 0050 4500 004c 0103  .$.......PE..L..
```

Using objdump, I got the following :

```
architecture: i386, flags 0x0000012f:
HAS_RELOC, EXEC_P, HAS_LINENO, HAS_DEBUG, HAS_LOCALS, D_PAGED
start address 0x0078353e

Characteristics 0x102
    executable
    32 bit words

Time/Date       XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Magic           010b    (PE32)
MajorLinkerVersion  11
MinorLinkerVersion  0
SizeOfCode      00381600
SizeOfInitializedData   00000800
SizeOfUninitializedData 00000000
AddressOfEntryPoint 0038353e
BaseOfCode      00002000
BaseOfData      00384000
ImageBase       00400000
SectionAlignment    00002000
FileAlignment       00000200
MajorOSystemVersion 4
MinorOSystemVersion 0
MajorImageVersion   0
MinorImageVersion   0
MajorSubsystemVersion   4
MinorSubsystemVersion   0
Win32Version        00000000
SizeOfImage     00388000
SizeOfHeaders       00000200
CheckSum        00000000
Subsystem       00000002    (Windows GUI)
DllCharacteristics  00008540
SizeOfStackReserve  00100000
SizeOfStackCommit   00001000
SizeOfHeapReserve   00100000
SizeOfHeapCommit    00001000
LoaderFlags     00000000
NumberOfRvaAndSizes 00000010

The Data Directory
Entry 0 00000000 00000000 Export Directory [.edata (or where ever we found it)]
Entry 1 003834e8 00000053 Import Directory [parts of .idata]
Entry 2 00384000 00000598 Resource Directory [.rsrc]
Entry 3 00000000 00000000 Exception Directory [.pdata]
Entry 4 00000000 00000000 Security Directory
Entry 5 00386000 0000000c Base Relocation Directory [.reloc]
Entry 6 003833b0 0000001c Debug Directory
Entry 7 00000000 00000000 Description Directory
Entry 8 00000000 00000000 Special Directory
Entry 9 00000000 00000000 Thread Storage Directory [.tls]
Entry a 00000000 00000000 Load Configuration Directory
Entry b 00000000 00000000 Bound Import Directory
Entry c 00002000 00000008 Import Address Table Directory
Entry d 00000000 00000000 Delay Import Directory
Entry e 00002008 00000048 CLR Runtime Header
Entry f 00000000 00000000 Reserved

There is an import table in .text at 0x7834e8

The Import Tables (interpreted .text section contents)
 vma:            Hint    Time      Forward  DLL       First
                 Table   Stamp     Chain    Name      Thunk


PE File Base Relocations (interpreted .reloc section contents)

There is a debug directory in .text at 0x7833b0

Type                Size     Rva      Offset

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00381544  00402000  00402000  00000200  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .rsrc         00000598  00784000  00784000  00381800  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .reloc        0000000c  00786000  00786000  00381e00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

So is this exe file a false one (hidden payload i.e.) or is it an obfuscated one ?

On virustotal, the actual file got a 10% detection rate. https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/e49be065137b8bd199848e334c3a4c2399bed97e71dd4f10e7d4a7f39e1c9e61/analysis/

Here is the md5 if you need :  48b0bd483d80617d6f4b33731811d248

EDIT:
Found out how this malware landed here, it was an attempts to download agony rootkit using a malicious thread spawned into lsass.exe. The initial attack vector was using Eternal Blue.
The file is corrupted because of the AV that stopped the download.

Comment: Seems like the file is corrupted. For example, as you pointed out - it has duplicate PE dos header and stub. Even if you remove the prepended header the file would still be corrupted and UPX won't be able to decompress it. Both versions don't even succeeded to run on my tests. So based on my quick and not comprehensive check - I don't think your binary is doing some magic or smart manipulations. If the payload itself isn't totally corrupted then you should probably be able to statically unpack it though...

Comment: How did you get this executable? Have you verified that it actually runs? (in an isolated VM, of course)

Comment: Each time SEP quarantine it onto the workstation and says that he made a call with lsass.exe to contact a specific IP to download a dll but it does not run by itself. What I'm thinking it's a payload and not an exe.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is being detected, then it seems likely that the first header is a decoy, sufficient to allow the file to load, and that the code that runs is a dropper for the content that begins with the second header.

Comment: what kind of approach to reverse such kind of malware could be adopted ?

Comment: Try to load the second PE header starting at +0x259 ?

Comment: try deleting the first 0x259 bytes from the file, leaving only one MZ header and everything after it.

Answer (score 0):

The malware was partly downloaded before the SEP client stop the attempt. That's why it gave no results.
Thank you for your help tho.

Comment: is it a valid answer to your primary question?